# SQL0420N Invalid character found in a character string argument of the function "DECFLOAT"

Tags: sql, db2

I got the error

> SQL0420N Invalid character found in a
> character string argument of the function "DECFLOAT"

when executing this query. I am puzzled as I cannot detect any error or problem anymore. Can you help me? My database is a IBM DB/2 running on Linux, version 10.5.

```
SELECT 
    RTRIM(b.TOPOB) AS TOPOB, 
    a.TESTID, 
    a.AFO AS AFO, 
    DATE(a.ERFTS) AS DATUM, 
    a.WAFERNUM, 
    CHAR(b.rownum * 100) || CHAR(b.colnum) AS COLNUM,
    CAST(b.devlres AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS ELEM_COS_RDIFF,
    CAST(d.gmrcoef AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS ELEM_HC,
    CAST(d.amrcoef AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS ELEM_LINEARITY_ERROR,
    CAST(b.devdres AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS ELEM_RCOS,
    CAST(b.devhres AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS ELEM_RGES,
    CAST(b.devestarres AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS ELEM_RSIN,
    CAST(d.pinangle AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS ELEM_SENS_NMAX,
    CAST(d.senres AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS ELEM_SENS_NMIN,
    CAST(b.devkres AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS ELEM_SIN_RDIFF 
FROM 
    bouser.mrchm_hdr AS a
INNER JOIN 
    bouser.mrchm_data AS b ON b.testid = a.testid
INNER JOIN 
    bouser.mrchc_data AS d ON d.testid = a.testid 
                          AND b.topob = d.topob 
                          AND b.rownum = d.rownum 
                          AND b.colnum = d.colnum
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        SERIENNR, 
        AKTMESSUNG 
    FROM 
        BOUSER.AFO0100 
    WHERE 
        Produkt LIKE 'Tethys%'
) T ON T.SERIENNR = a.WAFERNUM  
WHERE 
    T.AKTMESSUNG = 'Y' 
    AND DATE(a.ERFTS) > CURRENT DATE - 2247 DAYS 
    AND a.afo = 9053 
    AND a.lastview = 'Y'
ORDER BY 
    a.WAFERNUM, COLNUM;
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Remove code stepwise until the error disappears. Then you know which code part that is causing problems. The following step might be to find non-decimal column data raising the error.

Comment: the very last INNER JOIN / WHERE clause is causing the problem.

Comment: Great, now look for the data causing the exception.

Comment: I'd probably focus on the T.SERIENNR and a.WAFERNUM columns - what datatypes are they and what data do they contain? BTW you seem to be joining these 2 columns in both your JOIN and your WHERE - which doesn't look right

Comment: `SELECT * FROM (VALUES 1) A (A) JOIN (VALUES '', '1') B (B) ON B.B = A.A`. This simple query returns the same error. The optimizer probably implicitly converts `B.B` to `DECFLOAT (B.B)` to match the numeric data type of `A.A` and fails with a value which cant' be converted to numeric. You may look at the "Optimized Statement" section of an access plan of your query for such a rewrite.

Comment: BTW you seem to be joining these 2 columns in both your JOIN and your WHERE - which doesn't look right - I removed it from the WHERE section now

Comment: removing INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        SERIENNR, 
        AKTMESSUNG 
    FROM 
        BOUSER.AFO0100 
    WHERE 
        Produkt LIKE 'Tethys%'
) T ON T.SERIENNR = a.WAFERNUM  
WHERE 
    T.AKTMESSUNG = 'Y' 
    AND DATE(a.ERFTS) > CURRENT DATE - 2247 DAYS 
    AND a.afo = 9053 
    AND a.lastview = 'Y'
vanishes the error but isn't the solution

Comment: @SimonGiesen You still haven't answered the question about data types of columns above. A possible solution depends on this answer...

Comment: T.SERIENNR is CHAR(12 Octets) and a.WAFERNUM is BIGINT

Comment: So that’s your issue. It’s implicitly trying to cast T.SERIENNR to BIGINT and this is failing as there are values in this column that can’t be cast to BIGINT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that the query is basically correct. As T.SERIENNR is CHAR and a.WAFERNUM is BIGINT a direct assignment cannot be made. The correction would be:

```
ON T.SERIENNR = CHAR(a.WAFERNUM)
```